# Can I create a deployment from a list of pods?

Tags: kubernetes

My application isn't fully stateless yet, and part of it needs one stateful service per customer. Is there a way I can create a deployment that creates and maintains a single pod for each of a list of cust-foo, cust-bar etc, or do I need to create an almost identical deployment for each customer? The deployments would only differ by the customer ID, and new customers will be added infrequently.

StatefulSet doesn't appear to be the right thing to use here, because if I have cust-0, cust-1, cust-2 etc, I can't arbitrarily remove, say, cust-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pods are not identical, Deployment is not what you want.  Multiple identical deployments of size 1 seems not-unreasonable to me.  It's not like there's real overhead to that.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.